# Yarn errors when trying to create a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yarnpkg

I try to create a react app with the following command:

```
create-react-app eth-todo-list-react
```

This produces the following errors:

```
'yarnpkg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

'yarnpkg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn yarnpkg ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
```

It should say "success" and initialise a git depository. But I get the errors above instead. I have tried troubleshooting various methods including changing the path and installing yarn globally but when I do that and then re-try creating the react app again I get this error:

```
The directory eth-todo-list-react contains files that could conflict:

  package.json
  yarn.lock

Either try using a new directory name, or remove the files listed above.
```

If I delete this file and try creating the react app again, I get the first error again.

Comment: When your PATH is modified, the currently opened cmd windows aren't affected, you need to close them and reopen them.

Comment: Closing and opening cmd makes no difference. I always get the same error.

Comment: Try installing yarn first using "npm install yarn -g"

Comment: Already tried installing yarn globally, I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `npx` command,

`npx create-react-app my-project`

If you use `npx` you don't need to install packages globally like `create-react-app`.

All tell the `node -v` and `npm -v`

Comment: Now this actually worked. Thanks a lot. Could you please tell me exactly what npx is?

Comment: Check this blog post for more info https://blog.npmjs.org/post/162869356040/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner

Answer (score 0):

Get the version of your create-react-app by typing `create-react-app --version` into the console.  This built successfully for me using version 2.1.5.  You may need to update your create-react-app.
`npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
`npm create-react-app eth-todo-list-react`
should use the most current version of create-react-app.

Comment: Doesnt work, I get the same second conflicted files error